# How to bind getting data with value in input type - file?

Tags: vue.js

I am getting object's data from api and need show it in the input (so that i can change it later). With text values i made it with v-model. But how can i show getting file's name in input type file (and how can i change this file on future)

```
<tr v-for="item in this.$store.state.allItems" :key="item.id">
    <td><input type="text" v-model="item.name"></td>
    <td><input type="file" :value=""item.src></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Is this not simply a typo? `:value=""item.src` should be `:value="item.src"`

Comment: DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.

Comment: Oh yes that is a little old. How about displaying the image instead when you have the file? https://codepen.io/Atinux/pen/qOvawK/

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple typeo in your code `:value="item.src"` => `:value="item.src"` 
I hope this helps.